# How can I manually insert a timestamp into mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to manually be able to insert a timestamp value to mySQL database:

```
  $timestamp = "2018-05-15 00:00:00";
  $name = "Fred";


  $pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO data (timestamp,name) values(:timestamp,:name)');
  $pdo->execute(array(
       ':timestamp' => $timestamp,
       ':name' => $name
  ));
```

But it inserts always the date of now, not the date of my variable.

MYSQL table:

```
id | timestamp | name
----------------------
   |           |


id = int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
timestamp = timestamp (Standard: CURRENT TIMESTAMP, Attribute: ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
name = varchar (255)
```

Comment: is this correct values(:timestamp,name)

Comment: is this correct ':timestamp' => $timestamp,
       ':timestamp' => $name

Comment: why don't you just make that field a default as a current timestamp? very easy

Comment: Can you share the definition of your table? The given "timestamp" does not look like a timestamp after all....

Comment: @vSugumar Sorry, this was a typing mistake here in the question

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated the table defintion

Comment: Can you share the definition of your table, containing the data types? Something like `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: @NicoHaase Updated

Comment: do you have any other timestamp columns in the table?

Comment: are you inserting the hard coded value $timestamp = "2018-05-15 00:00:00"; are getting from somewhere else

Comment: `ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP` - thats a pretty obvious hint about what is happening here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually insert date in timestamp field then you should change its type from `timestamp (Standard CURRENT TIMESTAMP)` to `datetime`. Only then it will work, otherwise always it save current system time.

Read more about [datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: I tried datetime. But still it inserts NOW not the date of my variable...

Comment: Can you share your table structure again?